# For Each Action at Different Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I got a For Loop which controls specific column and copy entire row to another sheet.

But I couldn't find how can i get rows from different worksheet. I need to copy exactly same rows from "InputALL" worksheet instead of "OutputALL".

```
Dim bottomL As Integer
bottomL = Sheets("OutputALL").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each c In Sheets("OutputALL").Range("D1:D" & bottomL)
    If c.Value = "-----" Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Output2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Just change the references from `OutputALL` to `InputALL`

Comment: But condition check should remain on OututputALL. That's my problem.

Comment: Which rows from InputALL should be copied if you check only OutputALL rows? Should they have the same row index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is the answer you seek:

```
Dim bottomL As Integer
Dim c As Variant
bottomL = Sheets("OutputALL").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each c In Sheets("OutputALL").Range("D1:D" & bottomL)
    If c.Value = "-----" Then
        Sheets("InputALL").Range(c.Address).EntireRow.Copy _
            Worksheets("Output2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
Next c
```

By using Address of the cell, you can use it to specify the cell on same "coordinates" in different sheet.

Oh, and I have also added

```
Dim c As Variant
```

It is good habit to define variables explicitly (before there is value assigned to them).